# Kdiff3 always showing "Qt: qcolorFromCGColor: cannot convert from colorspace model: 0"

Tags: mercurial, kdiff3

On Mac, I installed kdiff3 to use with Mercurial to do

```
hg vdiff
```

but every time, it shows

```
Qt: qcolorFromCGColor: cannot convert from colorspace model: 0
Qt: qcolorFromCGColor: cannot convert from colorspace model: 0
Qt: qcolorFromCGColor: cannot convert from colorspace model: 0
Qt: qcolorFromCGColor: cannot convert from colorspace model: 0
Qt: qcolorFromCGColor: cannot convert from colorspace model: 0
Qt: qcolorFromCGColor: cannot convert from colorspace model: 0
Qt: qcolorFromCGColor: cannot convert from colorspace model: 0
```

is there some method to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be some issue with QT with mac 10.6. The following source says, you need to apply some patch. May be, this is available in latest version.

The source: http://qt.gitorious.org/~gberg/qt/qt-gberg/commit/e773b0486a4784994a900c03a